# Where is console object get defined?

Tags: javascript

Since currently we can use console.log to print out log information, I am wondering where is the console object get defined?

Comment: Not all js engine has `Console`.

Comment: Nowhere, it exists in firefox if you installed the FireBug , in IE if you installed the Developer Tools, but in Chrome it exists by default AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

- In the js engine that lies in browser(ie: [chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html)).
- Firebug has the [console](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) object.
- Nodejs server has its own console object.

Answer (score 1):

In the code of browser's developer tools. If the browser doesn't have native developer tools, it's defined by third-party dev tools like Firebug.

Comment: Wasn't the *Firebog* in *The Princess Bride*? Oh wait, that was the *Fire Swamp*. ;)

Comment: Thank *you* for reminding me of *The Princess Bride*. I think it's about time to watch it again.